# Select not render in Angular7 with Materialize

Tags: html, angular, materialize

I am trying to put a `select` in my application with Angular 7 and Materialize. However, this item is not displayed in the browser.

In the documentation and in some Stackoverflow posts it says that I must initialize the component with the following script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
});

// Or with jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').formSelect();
});

// Or
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

But it still doesn't work for me

[angular.json](http://angular.json)

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
  "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
]
```

[component.html](http://component.html)

```
<div class="row">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Cuenta 1</option>
    <option value="2">Cuenta 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
</script>
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you should try that, angular doesn't play well with jQuery and probably hasn't bootstrapped by the time your code runs.  If you must, try using setTimeout to see if that is the issue.

Your best bet would be to create a directive that would run on the element at the proper point in the angular lifecycle.  I'll try to add an answer when I have more time, I've done something similar with a plain javascript datetime picker control.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would appreciate if you can show me your proposal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to initialize the select only when it is already showing

Here is my .ts

```
import * as M from 'materialize-css';

setTimeout(() => {
  M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('mySelect'), {});
}, 30);
```

And my .html

```
<div class="row">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Cuenta 1</option>
    <option value="2">Cuenta 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```